# passing argument 5 of ‘myFunc’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]

Tags: c, matrix, compiler-errors

header.h

```
void myFunc(int, int, int, int, int [][2]);
```

definition

```
void myFunc(int a, int b, int c, int d, int matrix[][2]){
}
```

And here is where i call 'myFunc'

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    myFunc(a, b, c, d, matrix[i][2]);
}
```

In addition compiler gives me this error:

```
expected ‘int (*)[2]’ but argument is of type ‘int’
```

Where do i fail?

Thank you

Comment: Without a proper [mre] all we can do it guess. My guess is that you should pass only `matrix[i]` to the function, which means it's passed an array of two integers, which will decay to a pointer to an integer. In other words the call should be `myFunc(a, b, c, d, matrix[i])` and the function should be `void myFunc(int, int, int, int, int *)`

Comment: `matrix[i][2]` -> `matrix`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last argument to `myFunc` is of type

```
int matrix[][2],
```

which means "an 2D array of integers, where the array has two columns." On the other hand, when you're calling the function, you're passing as this argument

```
 matrix[i][2]
```

which means "the item in the matrix at row `i`, column `2`." That's an integer (it's actually out of bounds for the array - do you see why?) rather than a 2D matrix.

The specific way to fix this will depend on how `myFunc` works. Perhaps you meant to pass in `matrix` rather than `matrix[i][2]`? Or perhaps you meant to pass in `matrix[i]`, in which case the last parameter should have type `int[]` rather than `int[][2]`.